# confused in understanding an rbinom output

Tags: r

```
  p1 <- c(.25,.025,.025,.1,.2,.4)

  T <- sample(1:6,size=N,replace=TRUE, prob=someprobabilityvector)
  Y <- rbinom(N,1,p1[c(T)])
```

HI folks, I am new to R and programming in general and need some help with understanding sth basic. could someone explain to me one what is happening in vector Y above. I figure out what `p1[c(T)]` does above. But have no idea what vector Y is doing. All help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you have another question, maybe you should open another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your code creates a vector of six probabilities:

```
p1 <- c(.25,.025,.025,.1,.2,.4)
```

In the second line, you randomly choose `N` values from the numbers one to six (with replacement). The probability for each value is specified in `someprobabilityvector`. Hence, the function will return a vector of length `N` including values between 1 and 6

```
T <- sample(1:6,size=N,replace=TRUE, prob=someprobabilityvector)
```

In the third line, `N` random numbers from a binomial distribution with one trial and probablities specified in `p1[c(T)]` are generated. `c(T)` is the same as `T`: the vector including values from 1 to 6. The vector is used for indexing the vector `p1`. Hence, `p1[c(T)]` will return a vector including `N` values from vector `p1`.

```
Y <- rbinom(N,1,p1[c(T)])
```

Since the specified binomial distribution has one trial only, the vector `Y` will contain zeroes and ones.

Comment: @user2007598 As proof of concept, try `x <- table(Y);x/sum(x)` and notice that frequency of "1" is approx. 0.25 (as specified in `p1`) and freq. of 0 "everything else". In your case, 0 was not part of the primary sampling, but included when sampling the binomial distribution.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: what if I want to produce a Y vector only for sample method 2 or 3 or 4..... Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @user2007598 What do you mean by "sample method 2 or 3 or 4"?